# True or false matrix question $A^2=2A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is it true that $a, b, c, d, e, f \in R$ exist so that the following is possible?

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 && a && b \\
c && 1 && d \\
e && f && 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$A^2=2A$

I am not allowed to solve any kind of system with $a, b, c, d, e, f$ so I don't really know how to even approach this problem.

Comment: do you have any conditions on $A$, like being invertible or something?

Comment: @Mesmerizedstudent nothing, just the condition that $A^2=2A$

Comment: What is $R$? The set of real numbers?

Answer (score 8):

The fact that $A^2=2A$ implies $A^2-2A=0$ is a matrix polynomial equaling zero.

As any matrix has a [minimal polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)) and any matrix polynomial equaling zero is a multiple of the minimal polynomial, we learn that the minimal polynomial is one of:

$$x, x-2,~\text{or}~x^2-2x$$

This implies further that the eigenvalues of the matrix are some combination of $0$'s and $2$'s.

Note now that the trace of your matrix is equal to $3$ which could not be the sum of the eigenvalues (*possible sums being $0+0+0,0+0+2,0+2+2,2+2+2$*), a contradiction.

---

Related: [If $A^2=2A$, then $A$ is diagonalizable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619439/if-a2-2a-then-a-is-diagonalizable)

Answer (score 1):

We have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 && a && b \\
c && 1 && d \\
e && f && 1
\end{bmatrix}\end{eqnarray*}
Now calculate
\begin{eqnarray*}
A^2 &=&\begin{bmatrix}
1 +ac+be && 2a+bf && 2b+ad \\
2c+de && ac+1+df && 2d+cb \\
2e+cf && 2f+ae && be+df+1
\end{bmatrix} \\
2A&=&\begin{bmatrix}
2 && 2a && 2b \\
2c && 2 && 2d \\
2e && 2f && 2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{eqnarray*}
Consider the three equations on the leading diagonal
\begin{eqnarray*}
ac+be=1 \\
ac+df=1 \\
df+be=1 
\end{eqnarray*}
So $ac=be=df=\frac{1}{2}$. Now consider the $(1,2)$ entry $2a+bf=2a$, So $bf=0$ which contradicts $be=\frac{1}{2}$ or $df=\frac{1}{2}$.