# Is every self-inverse matrix diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, diagonalization

If $A=A^{-1}$, is there always a matrix C such that $C^{-1}AC$ is a diagonal
 matrix (containing only -1 and 1 in the main diagonal) ?

How can I check with PARI/GP, if a given matrix is diagonalizable ?

I only found out that $A=A^{-1}$ implies $C^{-1}AC=(C^{-1}AC)^{-1}$ for any
 invertible C, but this does not answer my question.

Additional question : If A has integer entries, is there always a matrix C with
 INTEGER values such that $C^{-1}AC$ is a diagoal matrix and $C^{-1}$ has also integer
 values ? For example, I did not find such a matrix for 
 A = [ [11,-16,-4] [9,-13,-3] [-6,8,1] ] yet.

Comment: OK, the theoretical part is done. What about PARI/GP, can I calculate diagonalizations with it ?

Comment: You didn't ask for diagonalizations; you asked if it was diagonalizable.

Comment: No, I only want to check the diagonalizability, but if you know how I can do the diagonalization in PARI/GP, this would be wonderful.

Comment: (The answer to the diagonalizable question is below.)  For this second question, assuming a is square "matdiagonal(mateigen(a,1)[1])".

Comment: Sorry, this does not work. But I found out, that it works as follows :  a=Mat([1,1;1,0]);c=mateigen(a);print(c^(-1)*a*c)
[-0.6180339887498948482045868344, -6.31088724 E-30; 0.E-29, 1.618033988749894848
204586834]
?

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/496338/18880 which was however closed. I think there are other duplicates, but cannot find them right now. Management summary: if the characteristic is not$~2$, this is OK. I characteristic$~2$ it fails miserably.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can rewrite that condition as $A^2 = I_2$. Therefore $A$ is a root of $X^2 - 1$.

- Case 1: the characteristic of the base field is not $2$ (for example $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$...), then this polynomial is split with simple roots, so $A$ is diagonalizable. The eigenvalues will be roots of $X^2 - 1$ so they will indeed only be either $1$ or $-1$.
- Case 2: the characteristic is $2$. Then $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix}\bigr)^2 = I_2$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 11):

$A$ is a root of the polynomial $f = x^{2} -1$, which has distinct roots. Thus its minimal polynomial, which divides $f$, has distinct roots. It follows that $A$ is diagonalizable.

---

This assumes that $1 \ne -1$. that is, the characteristic of the underlying field is not $2$. In characteristic $2$, the matrix
$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
satisfies $A = A^{-1}$, but it is *not* diagonalizable.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** in this case,
$$
A\times A=I\implies P(A) = 0, \\P = (X-1)(X+1)
$$

I assume that $1+1\neq 0$. In that case, $X\pm 1$ are different factors.

Some theorem (Lemme des noyaux in french, does anyone know the english term?)
states the second inequality in: $$E = \ker  P(A) =\ker (A-I) \oplus \ker (A+I)$$

Comment: +1 for giving the explicit diagonalization in terms of kernels.

Comment: OK if characteristic is not $2,$ but does not work for characteristic $2$.

Comment: yes, I have read the others answers.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to second question:  "matrank(mateigen(a)) = matsize(a)[1]", 
if you know the matrix a is square.  If not, append "= matsize(a)[2]"

Comment: According to PARI, [[0,-1],[0,1]] is a counterexample. The rank is 1 not equal matsize(a)[1] (=2), but [[1,-1],[0,1]] leads to the diagonal matrix [[0,0],[0,1]].

Comment: @Peter:  Which of the two matrices you wrote are you actually talking about?

Comment: @Peter:  Never mind, both things you wrote are incorrect.  The rank of [[0,-1],[0,1]] is clearly 1 because the second row is a multiple of the first.  Also the diagonalization of [[1,-1],[0,1]] is [[1,0],[0,1]].

Comment: I do not mean the diagonalization of [[1,-1],[0,1]], but using this matrix [[0,-1],[0,1]] is transformed to [[0,0],[0,1]].

Comment: ... which has rank one.  No idea what you're getting at.

Comment: I mean : [[0,-1][0,1]] is diagonalizable, although the given condition is not fulfilled.

Comment: Ah.  Finally see what you've been dancing around.  Editing.